# Simple message display system

Tags: php

I'm just starting with PHP. Working currently on simple message display system.

If I have following statement in one file `PageWithMessages.php`:

```
<span class="msg">
    <?php 
        if( $tableChange == true ) { echo "Table saved. ";}
        else if ( $rowChange == true ) { echo "Record saved. ";}
        else if ( $rowDelete == true ) { echo "Record deleted. ";}
        else if ( $rowNew == true ) { echo "New record created. ";}
    ?>
</span>
```

How can I pass the information of that variable `(e.g. $rowNew = true )` with following exiting statement from another file?

```
if($result) {
    header("location: PageWithMessages.php");
            // set $variable = true ??
    exit();
} else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

Any suggestion much appreciated.

Comment: is that span in `PageWithMessages.php`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly:

```
if($result) {
    header("location: PageWithMessages.php?var=1");
    exit();
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

then on PageWithMessage.php:

```
$var = (isset($_GET['var'])?true:false); // will be true
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have a two functions, one called `setMessage()`, and one `getMessage()`:

```
function setMessage($message)
{
 $_SESSION['message'] = $message;
}

function getMessage()
{
 if (isset($_SESSION['message']) {
  $message = $_SESSION['message'];
  unset($_SESION['message']);
  return $message;
 }
 return false;
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
if($result) {
    setMessage('Row changed');
    header("location: PageWithMessages.php");
            // set $variable = true ??
    exit();
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}

<?php if ($message = getMessage()): ?>
<span class="msg">
<?php echo $message; ?>
</span> #
<?php endif; ?>
```

Or you can use $_GET variables (url params) like `header("location: PageWithMessages.php?rowChanged=1");` and look for `$_GET['rowChanged'];`

Comment: Do I have to unset `$_SESSION['message']` after message have been displayed? Or it will get overwritten next time used?

Comment: Oh yeah! Do unset, sorry about that I wrote it on the go here. It will be overwritten but it will be available every time you open that page no matter if anything has changed.

Comment: Using `URL and $GET` sound like simplest and most probably best way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

```
include("your_file_including_variables_and_statements.php");
```

or

```
echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['variable']);
```

in case of PageWithMessages.php?variable=hello

Comment: Besides that, you could also redirect to PageWithMessages.php?variable=true. Then get that using `$_GET['variable']`.

Comment: OK, but where is my variable set to the TRUE?

Comment: How this bit of code is setting variable to true? `include("your_file_including_variables_and_statements.php");
` I don't understand that.

Comment: if you include file with variables, they're passed to your script thanks to your include

Comment: OK, is this performance friendly? Sound like sending a lot of data unnecessary.

Comment: @NewUser include only variables you need. PHP is not the most performance friendly

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities:

1) Send it as a GET parameter
2) Store it in the Session
3) Include the second script

Short example how:

@1) In the first file:

```
//replace XXXX accordingly with tableChange, rowChange, rowDelete or rowNew
header("location: PageWithMessages.php?action=XXXX");
```

and in PageWithMessage.php

```
<span class="msg">
    <?php 
        if( $_GET['action'] == "tableChange" ) { echo "Table saved. ";}
        else if ( $_GET['action'] == "rowChange" ) { echo "Record saved. ";}
        else if ( $_GET['action'] == "rowDelete" ) { echo "Record deleted. ";}
        else if ( $_GET['action'] == "rowNew" ) { echo "New record created. ";}
    ?>
</span>
```

@2) See [HERE](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) or inside the first file before header():

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['tableChange'] = true/false;
//same for other vars
```

and inside PageWithMessages.php

```
<span class="msg">
    <?php 
        session_start();
        if( $_SESSION['tableChange'] == true ) { echo "Table saved. ";}
        else if ( $_SESSION['rowChange'] == true ) { echo "Record saved. ";}
        else if ( $_SESSION['rowDelete'] == true ) { echo "Record deleted. ";}
        else if ( $_SESSION['rowNew'] == true ) { echo "New record created. ";}
    ?>
</span>
```

@3) In the first file instead of header:

```
$tableChange = true/false;
//same for other vars
include(dirname(__FILE__) . '\PageWithMessages.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php)

as far as I understand u want something like this

#### first.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['varaible'] = true;

if($result) {
    header("location: PageWithMessages.php");
    exit();
}else {
    die("Query failed");
}
```

#### PageWithMessages.php

```
session_start();
$sessionVariable = $_SESSION['varaible'];

<span class="msg">
    <?php 
        if( $sessionVariable == true ) { echo "Table saved. ";}        
    ?>
</span>
```

Comment: Set when exiting the file and once used to display the messsage unset?